# Read set amount of words from multiple text files and save as new files

Tags: python

I have several hundred text files of books (file001.txt, file002.txt etc), I want to read the first 3,000 words from each file and save it as a new one (eg file001_first3k.txt, file002_first3k.txt).

I've seen terminal solutions for Mac and Linux (I have both) but they seem to be for displaying to the terminal window and for set amount of characters, not words.

Posting this in Python as it seems that it is more likely to have a solution here than for terminal and I have some experience of Python.

Comment: Define "word". Do you mean sequences separated by space characters?

Comment: Yes, that's right, split by spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will get you started, it makes the assumption that it is ok to split on spaces in order to determine the number of words.

```
import os
import sys

def extract_first_3k_words(directory):
    original_file_suffix = ".txt"
    new_file_suffix = "_first3k.tx"
    filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(directory)
        if f.endswith(original_file_suffix) and not f.endswith(new_file_suffix)]

    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename, "r") as original_file:

            # Get the first 3k words of the file
            num_words = 3000
            file_content = original_file.read()
            words = file_content.split(" ")
            first_3k_words = " ".join(words[:num_words])

            # Write the new file
            new_filename = filename.replace(original_file_suffix, new_file_suffix)
            with open(new_filename, "w") as new_file:
                new_file.write(first_3k_words)

            print "Extracted 3k words from: %s to %s" % (filename, new_filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print "Usage: python file_splitter.py <target_directory>"
        exit()
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    extract_first_3k_words(directory)
```

Comment: That's, great, thanks @silleknarf. I just had to make a couple of changes to get it to run but otherwise it worked as I hoped: line 6 .tx to .txt; both print commands I had to add parentheses

Comment: Just a heads-up: If the files are very large, this may fail; it reads the whole file into memory first.